# Python script execution during Azure ADB cluster bootup

Tags: python-3.x, azure, cluster-computing, azure-databricks

From Azure ADB Cluster, once before Cluster boot-up is done, I need to execute one Python script every time, How can we achieve this?

Every time during Cluster launch, python script should be executed by default. Any such kind of option is available please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found "Init Scripts path" as part of the Cluster creation, but it is asking for only abfss:// path. Not accepting /mnt path.

Comment: And dbfs:/ path is deprecated it is showing..  still i tried but getting below error.

Actual error : dbfs:/databricks/test/bootup.py: No such file or directory.

Comment: it should be a shell script that then can call your python script

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research, found that we can implement this in 2 ways:

1. Using "Init script path" while creating Cluster
2. From ADB > Workflows > Create job